# Do Fords send telematics information even when FordPass is not enabled?

Tags: ford

Do modern Ford vehicles send telematics data back to Ford even if the owner of the vehicle does not activate or subscribe to FordPass?

I read Ford's "privacy statement" and it seemed to imply that Fords do indeed send telematics data at all times regardless of the owner's wishes, but in a "de-identified" form. I don't see how telematics data can be "de-identified". I mean if the GPS coordinates of the vehicle show it parked in your driveway all night, it is pretty clear to whom the vehicle belongs even without a VIN.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably safe to assume that unless they specifically say they are not passing any information that they are doing it.

I know that GM does this with OnStar where even though I don't subscribe, I get notified from the dealer that my oil needs changed or other maintenance is needed.

Comment: Was going to mention the same thing about GM ... I get them on my 2018 Silverado from OnStar. I don't really much like it, but I guess it is what it is.

Comment: The only way I know of to stop OnStar is to disconnect it in the vehicle.  For now, at least, I don't think it's required to be active in order for the vehicle to function.  That may not be the case for newer vehicles and other brands.  The whole "big brother is watching" scenario is coming soon to a vehicle near you.

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but that's what the OBDIII specification would be ... which should never come to fruition. Not only would it check to see what your emissions are doing and report it back to the government via road side sensors, it would also give them all of the other status indicators of the vehicle, such as speed and location. Definitely "big brother" status.

Comment: OBD lll has been available for quite awhile. The auto manufacturers have been reluctant to utilize it for fear of loss of sales as consumers would not tolerate such invasion of privacy. Just over 6 years ago the federal government mandated it to go into every new car by a certain year that I don't remember. So yes it's something in our future. This system reports a lot of info including your weight, speed, location , when and where and anything any sensor is able to monitor.

Comment: @Jupiter - I did more than a cursory search for actual OBD3 sightings ... and ... there's nothing I can find. If you have hard evidence OBD3 exists today or even a definite deployment plan, I'd really be interested in seeing it. I've read about what "possibly" an OBD3 system would do for an against us, but I've not seen a single thing related to a finalization of the spec, nor when it *might* be deployed. Everything I'm seeing is conjecture at this point (and should stay that way). Please, if you have credible information on it, I'd be more than happy to entertain.

Comment: @Paulster2 - the availability of OBD lll source I had was from an Auto Enginuity scanner preface in there instruction manual. Probably not a real good source. But in the last days of Obama's term I heard a clip from the local news that OBDlll would be mandated for all new cars starting in a year that I don't remember.